# data passing from blocks to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have obtained data from server using following code.Now i want to reflect the same on other view controller having table view cells.How can I pass data from this singleton class to the the class having Table View cells.Please help with some code in objective c.Thanks in advance!

```
-(NSDictionary *)getResponseFromSearchByRoutewithUrl:(NSString *)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSDictionary *responseDictionary;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //check if we encountered an error
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }else{
            //get and check the HTTP status code
            NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
            if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
                NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %ld", (long)HTTPStatusCode);
            }

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                if(data != nil){
                    NSError *parseError = nil;
                    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
                    NSLog(@"The response is - %@",responseDictionary);

                }
            }];
        }
    }];


    [task resume];
    return responseDictionary;
}
```

Comment: just clear your ques "pass data having Table View cells", here are many ways to pass data from one to another view.

Comment: I have a view controllerA that has tableview on it.And a class NetworkManger in which i have defined the above method.I am getting the response from server but I am not able to reflect this response on the cells of table view on ViewController A.I am a new developer,so need your help with code.

Comment: Check this answer https://gist.github.com/jitendrabenzatine/31c0e6171f8df8a878a363a5d240ebf7

Comment: show your `responseDictionary` response, edit your ques.

Comment: @Lovely check my repository. All thing you want is there

Comment: @Jecky,I have to do this task using NSUrl Session.Can you give some example of NSUrlSession,please

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef void (^HttpCompletionBlock)     (NSString *token, NSError *error);

-(NSDictionary *)getResponseFromSearchByRoutewithUrl:(NSString *)url  :(HttpCompletionBlock)completionHandler {
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSDictionary *responseDictionary;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //check if we encountered an error
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }else{
        //get and check the HTTP status code
        NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %ld", (long)HTTPStatusCode);
        }



        [task resume];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            if(data != nil){
                NSError *parseError = nil;
                NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
                NSLog(@"The response is - %@",responseDictionary);
                return completionHandler(responseDictionary,nil);

            }
            else {
                 return completionHandler(nil,error);

            }
        }];
    }
}];

}
```

WS call function

```
- (IBAction)bankLoginPressed:(id)sender
{
    [HTTPClass getResponseFromSearchByRoutewithUrl:@"URL" :^(NSDictionary *dic, NSError *error) {
        if(error == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"access code ==  %@ ",token);
        }
        else
        {       
            NSLog(@"Error ==  %@ ",error);
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: In call function,what is sendLogin ?

Comment: This doesn't reflect the response dictionary to the table view cells..as the ViewcontrollerB gets load first and it returns responseDictionary later due to which the number of rows becomes 0.

Comment: @Lovely : had u tried reload table or insert row in main thread ?

Comment: No because the tableview is on other view controller...how can i do it from this class ,here i have handled ConnectionManagement only ?

Comment: just pass delegate or NSNotification

Comment: Sir,its like I know that this can be achieved through delegates and NSNotifcation but  I am not able to implement through code and that's why I asked you for help.I am a fresher...and have not much idea of using delegates.It would be very grateful if you give example.